# Certain ogg files not playing in java (possibly size-related?)

Tags: java, arrays, audio, ogg

I have a sound class that plays audio files. However, certain ogg files are not working when played. I am not sure if it is due to the files' formats or the sizes of the files.

The problem seems to happen with the files low in size since the files that do work are 6.7+ kb or more and the ones that do not are 6 kb or less.

However, I tried adding generated tones at the end of one of the nonfunctional oggs with Audacity, increasing the file to 7.5 kb, but it still did not work.

Here is the Sound class I used for playing the files:

```
  import static javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
  import static javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.URL;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Arrays;

  import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
  import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
  import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
  import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info;
  import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
  import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
  import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

  /**
   * The {@code Sound} class plays audio from a wav, ogg, or mp3 file
   * with wav working the best in a new thread
   * <p>
   * Here are some examples of how the {@code Sound} object can be initialized:
   * <blockquote><pre>
   *     Sound soundOne = new Sound("pathToFile/music.wav", true);
   *     Sound soundTwo = new Sound(new File("pathToFile/music.wav"), true);
   *     Sound soundThree = new Sound(ClassName.class.getResource(pathToFile/music.wav), true);
   * </pre></blockquote>
   * <p>
   * The class {@code Sound} includes methods for playing audio, stopping audio, changing
   * the volume, getting the duration if a wav, get whether the audio is stopped, get
   * whether the audio is finished, and changing the input file
   *
   */
  public class Sound {
      /**
       * Whether or not the music should be playing in a loop
       */
      private boolean loopable;
      /**
       * Whether or not a URL was given
       */
      private boolean isUrl;

      /**
       * The String name of the file
       */
      private String fileName;

      /**
       * The URL location of the file
       */
      private URL fileUrl;

      /**
       * The volume at which the sound plays at
       */
      private double volume = 1.0;
      /**
       * The duration of the audio file in milliseconds
       */
      private double durationInMilliseconds;

      private ArrayList<PlayingSound> playingSounds = new ArrayList<>();

      /**
       * Initializes a newly created {@code Sound} object given a String file name
       * @param fileName    Path of the file to be played
       * @param loopable    Whether or not the audio should loop
       * @throws UnsupportedAudioFileException    Thrown if the file is not supported
       * @throws IOException  Thrown if there is a problem with the given file
       */
      public Sound(String fileName, boolean loopable) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
          isUrl = false;
          this.fileName = fileName;
          this.loopable = loopable;
          if(fileName.endsWith(".wav")) {
              final File file = new File(fileName);
              AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
              AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
              long frames = stream.getFrameLength();
              durationInMilliseconds = 1000 * ((double) frames/format.getFrameRate());
          }
      }

      /**
       * Initializes a newly created {@code Sound} object given a File object
       * @param inputFile    File to be played
       * @param loopable     Whether or not the audio should loop
       * @throws UnsupportedAudioFileException    Thrown if the file is not supported
       * @throws IOException  Thrown if there is a problem with the given file
       */
      public Sound(File inputFile, boolean loopable) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
          isUrl = false;
          this.fileName = inputFile.toString();
          this.loopable = loopable;
          if(fileName.endsWith(".wav")) {
              AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inputFile);
              AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
              long frames = stream.getFrameLength();
              durationInMilliseconds = 1000 * ((double) frames/format.getFrameRate());
          }
      }

      /**
       * Initializes a newly created {@code Sound} object given a URL object
       * @param url          URL to audio file
       * @param loopable     Whether or not the audio should loop
       * @throws UnsupportedAudioFileException    Thrown if the file is not supported
       * @throws IOException  Thrown if there is a problem with the given file
       */
      public Sound(URL url, boolean loopable) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
          isUrl = true;
          fileUrl = url;
          String urlString = url.toString();
          fileName = urlString.substring(Math.max(urlString.lastIndexOf('\\'), urlString.lastIndexOf('/')) + 1);
          this.loopable = loopable;
          if(fileUrl.getFile().endsWith(".wav")) {
              AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileUrl);
              AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
              long frames = stream.getFrameLength();
              durationInMilliseconds = 1000 * ((double) frames/format.getFrameRate());
          }
      }

      /**
       * Plays the audio from the given source
       */
      public final void play() {
          playingSounds.add(new PlayingSound());
      }

      /**
       * Stops the audio from playing
       */
      public final void stop() {
          for(PlayingSound ps : playingSounds)
              ps.stop();
      }

      /**
       * Changes the volume of the audio
       * @param volume    Volume to change to
       */
      public final void changeVolume(double volume) {
          if(volume > 1 || volume < 0)
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: Volume must be between 0 and 1");
          this.volume = volume;
      }

      /**
       * The AudioFormat to specify the convention to represent the data
       * @param inFormat  The format of the audio file
       * @return          The necessary format information from the inFormat
       */
      private AudioFormat getOutFormat(AudioFormat inFormat) {
          final int ch = inFormat.getChannels();
          final float rate = inFormat.getSampleRate();
          return new AudioFormat(PCM_SIGNED, rate, 16, ch, ch * 2, rate, false);
      }

      /**
       * Gives duration in milliseconds if .wav file
       * @return  Duration in milliseconds if .wav file
       * @throws Exception    Thrown if file is not .wav
       */
      public double getDuration() throws Exception {
          if(!isUrl && fileName.endsWith(".wav") || isUrl && fileUrl.getFile().endsWith(".wav"))
              return durationInMilliseconds;
          throw new Exception("Error: Length can only be determined for .wav files");
      }

      /**
       * Returns whether or not the audio is playing
       * @return Whether or not the audio is playing
       */
      public final boolean isStopped() {
          for(PlayingSound ps : playingSounds)
              if(!ps.isStopped())
                  return false;
          return true;
      }

      /**
       * Returns whether or not the audio has finished playing (has exited loop)
       * @return Whether or not the audio has finished playing (has exited loop)
       */
      public final boolean isFinished() {
          for(PlayingSound ps : playingSounds)
              if(!ps.isFinished())
                  return false;
          return true;
      }

      /**
       * Changes the input location for the audio
       * @param url   The URL to replace the audio source
       * @throws UnsupportedAudioFileException    Thrown if the file is not supported
       * @throws IOException  Thrown if there is a problem with the given file
       */
      public final void changeInput(URL url) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
          isUrl = true;
          fileUrl = url;
          if(fileUrl.getFile().endsWith(".wav")) {
              AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileUrl);
              AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
              long frames = stream.getFrameLength();
              durationInMilliseconds = 1000 * ((double) frames/format.getFrameRate());
          }
      }

      private void removeInternalSound(PlayingSound ps) {
          playingSounds.remove(ps);
      }

      /**
       * Returns the volume the sound is currently set to
       * @return The volume of the audio
       */
      public final double getVolume() {
          return volume;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return String.format("String[name: %s, loopable: %b]", fileName, loopable);
      }

      private class PlayingSound {
          private boolean stop = false;
          private boolean finished = false;
          private Thread playingSound;

          PlayingSound() {
              playingSound = new Thread(() -> {
                  do {
                      try {
                          AudioInputStream in;
                          if(!isUrl)
                              in = getAudioInputStream(new File(fileName));
                          else
                              in = getAudioInputStream(fileUrl);
                          final AudioFormat outFormat = getOutFormat(in.getFormat());
                          final Info info = new Info(SourceDataLine.class, outFormat);
                          try(final SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info)) {
                              if(line != null) {
                                  line.open(outFormat);
                                  line.start();
                                  AudioInputStream inputMystream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(outFormat, in);
                                  stream(inputMystream, line);
                                  line.drain();
                                  line.stop();
                              }
                          }
                      }
                      catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException | IOException e) {
                          throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                      }
                  } while(loopable && !stop);
                  finished = true;
                  removeInternalSound(this);
              });
              playingSound.start();
          }

          /**
           * Streams the audio to the mixer
           * @param in    Input stream to audio file
           * @param line  Where the audio data can be written to
           * @throws IOException  Thrown if given file has any problems
           */
          private void stream(AudioInputStream in, SourceDataLine line) throws IOException {
              byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
              for(int n = 0; n != -1 && !stop; n = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) {
                  byte[] bufferTemp = new byte[buffer.length];
                  for(int i = 0; i < bufferTemp.length; i += 2) {
                      short audioSample = (short) ((short) ((buffer[i + 1] & 0xff) << 8) | (buffer[i] & 0xff));
                      audioSample = (short) (audioSample * volume);
                      bufferTemp[i] = (byte) audioSample;
                      bufferTemp[i + 1] = (byte) (audioSample >> 8);
                  }
                  buffer = bufferTemp;
                  line.write(buffer, 0, n);
              }
          }

          void stop() {
              stop = true;
          }

          boolean isStopped() {
              return stop;
          }

          boolean isFinished() {
              return finished;
          }

      }

  }
```

Here is a class that can be used to test the above Sound class if you replace pathToFile with the path to the file:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, InterruptedException {
        Sound test = new Sound("pathToFile", false);
        test.play();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

}
```

Here are three working ogg files:

File a:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hwgor2xk0ief7ui/workingOne.ogg

File b:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4n14lxpvmw0ezpd/workingTwo.ogg

File c:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/749zrcglz1jpfow/workingThree.ogg

Here are three failing ogg files:

File d:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bwsu4ouwu06rfao/failedFile.ogg

File d plus extra generated tones to increase the size past that of the working file a above:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t7q4wmh4ljqvz3a/failedFile2.ogg

File e:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tddn22crdkvwawl/click.ogg

There may be a few libraries that are required to get the ogg files working with the given class. If no files work, compile the libraries in the given zip with the given programs (probably using an IDE):

The (java jar) libraries included are JLayer 1.0.1, Jogg 0.0.7, JOrbis 0.0.17-1, MP3 SPI 1.9.5, Tritonus-share 0.3.7.4, and Ogg Vorbis SPI 1.0.3.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tqrj5w4vs32a3h8/lib.zip

**UPDATE:**

I added a lot of the tone I added to file d earlier (30 sec worth) to file d to see if it would change anything, and it worked.

So, I decided to start cutting audio until the point where the audio failed to play.

Oddly enough, I cut shorter than file d's length, and it was working until I cut down to a certain point.

Let's call the shorter version of file d that works file f and the one that is shorter than that and doesn't work file g.

Additionally, if I change the export quality setting from 10/10 to 5/10 in Audacity, the software where I did this, the playback does not work. Let's call this file h.

Here are each of the aforementioned files:

File f:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ore4bfgb0va2gw7/fileF.ogg

File g:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/zq000zhlup9hiu1/fileG.ogg

File h:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4ojj7gv9x92z9mi/fileH.ogg

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you *describe* which libraries you’re using, rather than expecting people to look through an external zip file.  Also note that if that zip file is ever removed, your question will be close to impossible to answer, and will have little value to future readers;  but if you tell us what libraries you’re using, we can always track down those libraries ourselves.

Comment: @VGR I have added the library names and versions. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: It appears `in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)` always returns zero for the problematic files.  My guess is that it’s a bug in Vorbis SPI, JOrbis, or Jogg.  Or, they may explicitly document that there are some Ogg sub-formats they don’t support.

Comment: @VGR That could be the case. The issue does not occur if the ogg is converted to a wav file and used.